# Android and extends about two activities

Tags: android

I have a problem. How I can extends for two activities. I have a activity which must extends two other activities, but I can't extends about two activities. How I can do this another way?
I need this because one activity extends Activity, but in this activity must extends MapActivity too because I'm using mapView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java you can not extend two classes at the same time. There are several approaches:

You can have one of the classes as a member field (lets call this `A`) and the other one (lets call this `B`) to be extended. Thus you will have access to the the private and protected methods of `B` and to all public methods of `B`. After all the main reason of extending an `Activity` is to get all `Context`'s methods. From then on your own activities are just adding up methods. However, you can use them even without inheriting.

If it is possible you can make `A` extend `B` and then make your new activity extend only `A`. Thus all the methods of both activities will be inherited.

**EDIT** After your edit I can say you are already in case 2 of my explanation. `MapActivity` is an `Activity` by itself. You need not extend both. Extend just `MapActivity`.

Answer (score 3):

[MapActivity extends Activity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity), so you just have to inherit from MapActivity.

```
class YourClass extends MapActivity
```